# how to download a video and store in the database while showing the progress at the same time in android

Tags: android, progress

Hoping you have a great day! I am stuck with a problem such that I am not able to show the progress of video download properly. The main idea is that I am downloading a video from the server and storing in the DB as blob. At the same time I am showing the actual progress of the file downloaded. The video download and the progress bar are working fine but I am not able to store it in the DB. I have used AsyncTask.doInBackground and AsyncTask.publishProgress methods respectively. Both are working fine. But it is not able to store in the DB.

The code is as follows:

```
    public class DownloadVideoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                String videoUrl = downloadAndStoreVideoInDB(url[0]);
                return videoUrl;
                //String videoUrl = downloadVideo(url[0]);
                //return videoUrl;
            }
            protected void doProgress(int val){
                publishProgress(val);

            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(final Integer... values) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);

                if(progressBar.getProgress()>=progressBar.getMax()){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    syncBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                /**
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        for(int i = 0; i <= values[0]; i++){
                            final int value = i;
                            try{
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                                ie.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                                public void run(){

                                    progressBar.setProgress(value);
                                    if(progressBar.getProgress()>=progressBar.getMax()){
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        //Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        syncBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
                new Thread(runnable).start();
                */
                //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }

            //Downloads the video from the specified url.
            public String downloadAndStoreVideoInDB(String path){
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG , "URL " +path);
                    URL url = new URL(path);
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream videoStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream videoBufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream(videoStream,128);
                    ByteArrayBuffer videoByteArray = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);

                    //Percentage calculation for progress bar is pending.
                    //doProgress(10);
                    //Get the bytes one by one
                    int current = 0;
                    long total = 0;
                                    //keeps on executing does not come out!
                    while((current = videoBufferedStream.read())!= -1){
                        total += current;

                        //Show the download progress
                        doProgress((int)((total*100)/lengthOfFile)); // here I show the progress

                        videoByteArray.append((byte)current);
                        //Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(current));


                    }
//This code never reaches hence not able to insert in the DB    

                dbAdapter.insertVideoBytesInVideoDownloadsTable(id, videoByteArray.toByteArray());
                    //doProgress((int)((total*100)/lengthOfFile));

                    videoBufferedStream.close();

                }catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                    ex.printStackTrace();


                    }
                return path;    
            }



            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You **DONT** store that kind of content into a database.. You store a **LINK** to that content.

Answer (score 1):

Store video in local path(that is in sdcard or in phone memory) and store that local path in Database.When you want to play that video take local url from database and go to the local url path and play the video.